# Geany doesn't complete Python keywords

Tags: debian, python, autocomplete, geany

Geany 1.33, Debian 10, autocomplete command - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.

When I put any Python keywords (`print, class`, etc.), Geany doesn't complete them, and I even don't see any Python keywords in an autocomplete drop list.

Comment: Might be answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490915/geany-auto-completion-how-does-it-work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Done. I dropped it and started use Vim with SpaceVim.